# IF Function with 3 conditions and outcomes

Tags: excel

I'm looking to create a formula with 3 conditions. It is currently only working with 2 conditions. Here's what I'm looking for:

A1 has a number

If the number is >15 then I want it to show Text 1

If the number is between 10 and 15, then I want it to show Text 2

If the number is between 5 and 10, then I want it to show Text 3

If the number is lower than 5, I don't want anything

Anybody got an idea?

Comment: I'm recommending you move this to SuperUser: https://superuser.com/

Comment: @MattMorgan Actually it is a programming question.  Don't know if Super User would be better.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen fair enough, but basing my comment on: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155487/if-i-had-a-question-with-excel-which-site-would-i-use  and the accepted answer to it: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/155488

Comment: @MattMorgan Thanks for pointing this out, I did know this.  Certainly I agree then that the end user Excel questions don't belong here.  This one is "codish," sort of :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `IF` function:

```
=IF(A1 > 15, "Text 1", IF(A1 >= 10, "Text 2", IF(A1 >= 5, "Text 3", "")))
```

Note that the nature of the `IF` function as used above necessitates also having a value should the value of `A1` be less than 5.  In this case, I just use empty string, per your updated requirements.

Answer (score 1):

If you have OFFICE 365 Excel you can use IFS():

```
=IFS(A1>15,"Text1",A1>=10,"Text2",A1>=5,"Text3",A1<5,"")
```

Or instead of nested IF all versions can use INDEX/MATCH:

```
=INDEX({"","Text3","Text2","Text1"},MATCH(A1,{-1E+99,5,10,15.01}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Nested `IF`:

```
=IF(A1>15,"Text 1",IF(A1>=10,"Text 2","Text 3"))
```

---

### More Information:

- Office.com : [IF Function (Excel)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2)